# How to pass parameter to javascript function that contains web service results?

Tags: .net, javascript, wcf, web-services

I use this function in javascript to call web service (WCF):

```
function Do(caller)
{
   MyService.GetClient(some_id, CallBackGetClient);
}

function CallBackGetClient(WebServiceResult)
{
   var result = WebServiceResult;
   etc.
}
```

Now I want to pass parameter (caller) to CallBackGetClient function so I can make dictinction who called Do() function. How to pass a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put put it inside an anonymous function, for which you use the same function signature as the expected callback.

```
function Do(caller)
{
   MyService.GetClient(some_id, function(webServiceResult) {
       CallBackGetClient(webServiceResult, caller);
   });
}
```

Here you are passing an anonymous function to `GetClient` as the callback. That function will take the expected web service result as its argument, but inside that function, you're turning around and invoking the *real* `CallBackGetClient`, adding `caller` as a second argument. This works because `caller` gets "trapped" inside the scope of the anonymous function so it'a still usable.

And this right here is the best thing about Javascript.

Comment: How then get both two in CallBackGetClient ?

Comment: CallBackGetClient will look like this: CallBackGetClient(WebServiceResult, caller) then?

Comment: I think I understand what you're after. I updated the answer. Hope that helps.